# word/sentence alignment for English document

Tags: text-mining, nlp, machine-translation

I have an English document, which is preprocessed into two versions. I want to align words or sentences from these two versions of the document. A simple example is as below:

```
I don't want to go there. My e-mail address ok.
```

should be aligned with

```
I do n't want to go there my email address ok
```

Or the tokens from the first sentence are aligned correctly with the tokens in the 2nd sentence. I have tried some sequence alignment methods, which do not perform well. Considering there are alignment tools for machine translation, automatic alignment for English should be easier right?

Comment: Could you say what bio-sequence alignment methods you have tried?

Comment: Actually not bio-sequence in particular, I have tried SequenceMatcher from difflib. I have also tried another one but had error running aligner. Do you have any experience on this?

Comment: It looks like the most common mistakes are insertions of spaces and deletions of punctuation and replacing punctuation by spaces. So in particular s(" ","-") should be less of a penalty than s("a","p") in Smith-Waterman. That is the sort of parameter setting I wanted you to include in what you had already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use kaldi's `align-text` which align two sentences using Levenshtein distance.

Code: https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/master/src/bin/align-text.cc